# How can I remove the texture from an image using matlab?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, textures, fft

How can I use the fourier transform to find out the frequency components which are responsible for the texture on the surface?

Then I have to remove them to have a smooth surface without texture.

[**This**](http://www.flickr.com/photos/63036721@N02/5733958932/in/photostream) is the image.

Thanks

Comment: What have you tried yourself to get to a solution? As I see it, you can make a smooth surface out of it, but that's just the mean value of all pixel values (which can be done by Fourier analysis of course).

Comment: I applied a low pass filter in the frequency domain, but I don't know if this is the right solution.

Comment: Well, first of all there is no such thing as a 'right solution' (some solutions might work OK, some might work sometimes, some might not work at all). Whether your solution is OK depends completely on what you want to do with the image afterwards.

Comment: you could put up the image that you got from the low pass filtering. Generally it should remove the texture.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use Fourier Transform and analyze frequency components, then removing high frequency components of the image gives a close effect of low pass filter. However, it does not seem natural since you also manipulate the phase of the image. As people suggest, I also advise low pass filter. More specifically, if you want the color of the given image, you may want to try Gaussian Filter.

Comment: Can you please explain how a Gaussian filter is better at keeping the color of an RGB image?