# difference between the gaussian LPF and ideal LPF in frequency domain in image processing

Tags: matlab, image-processing, textures, fft

I am working with the same image and I also need to remove the texture from the image posted in this link

[How can I remove the texture from an image using matlab?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6080393/how-can-i-remove-the-texture-from-an-image-using-matlab)

Discussions were made on this and I'm quite confused which filter(gaussian LPF or ideal lowpass) is really needed and what is the reason behind this.Which frequencies contribute for this texture????please can someone explain me!

Answer (score 6):

An ideal low pass filter will keep all spatial frequencies below a nominal spatial frequency, and remove all spatial frequencies above it.  Unfortunately, a true ideal low pass filter has infinite support (i.e., has an infinitely large non-zero spatial extend). Even a practical approximation to an ideal low pass filter has large spatial support.

A Gaussian, on the other hand, isn't ideal in terms of which frequencies it filters out.  A Gaussian in the spatial domain turns out to be a Gaussian in the spatial frequency domain.  That is, it doesn't produce very sharp spatial frequency selectivity.  The advantage though is that the spatial support of the filter is small.  People use Gaussian filters for this because they are convenient mostly.  Filtering with a Gaussian tends to look "natural" compared to ideal low pass filters, which can generate ringing artifacts.

A Lanczos filter (windowed sinc filter) is also another choice as it will have a small spatial support and will approximate an ideal filter better than a Gaussian.

However, which is better for your image largely depends on what you want to do.  While there's significant theory behind it, qualitative choices like this in image processing are largely an art.

Comment: Hey Chris what do you mean by "low pass filter has infinite support  (i.e., has an infinitely large non-zero spatial extend)"? I've tried implementing an ideal low pass filter by simply removing all the frequency bins below a certain threshold and this does produce some weird ringing artifacts in my images.

Comment: I meant that, in theory, the space domain equivalent of an ideal low pass filter has infinite spatial extent.  The ringing you see is exactly the impact of this infinite spatial extent.  My point with the post is that a Lanczos filter is a way of modifying this ideal frequency response to achieve a tradeoff between an ideal frequency domain filter and smaller, _nicer_ spatial response.  See [this link here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ringing_artifacts) for more detail on why the ringing occurs.

Answer (score 0):

The type of filter you are looking for is ideally nonlinear:
  smoothing in areas without large-scale gradients (edges), and
  little smoothing close to edges to be preserved.

Here are two alternatives:

The Kuwahara filter: 
http://homepage.tudelft.nl/e3q6n/publications/1999/PAA99DRBDPVLV/PAA99DRBDPVLV.pdf

Enhanced shortening flow (Figure 8) in: 
http://www.cs.jhu.edu/~misha/Fall07/Papers/intro-to-scalespace.pdf

In the second filter (Enhanced shortening flow), you can
vary the scale parameter and the nonlinear function,
h(Lw) on page 17. Thus, more trimming possibilities.

Ideally, the filter is completely isotropic
(same frequency effect on each possible angle).

Michael